# can we join 2 HTML pattern in one input?

Tags: html, pattern-matching

I have this pattern in HTML for an ID login :

```
[0-9]{6} (need 6 numbers)
```

and i just learned some users have a letter before numbers so it became :

```
^(a|A)([0-9]{6})$
```

and i want to know if it's possible to join the two pattern in one (write 6number or 1 letter + 6 numbers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can join the two patterns with the "|" character.
Please, try this: 
[a-z]{1}\d{6}|[A-Z]{1}\d{6}

Comment: i try this, ty :) EDIT: PERFECT :*

Answer (score 0):

`^(a|A)?([0-9]{6})$`

By adding the **?** we are saying the first capturing group must appear either zero or one time.